# Honda Accord 2Door Coupe 2004 - Cruise Control Problem

Tags: honda, accord, cruise-control

my GF's Honda Accord has recently begun acting up in regards to its cruise control.

holding down the switch, the light turns on, however pressing set, accel, or decel, does not do anything, the car acts as if cruise control was off.

releasing the switch, the light turns off.

I have read about testing the switch while honking the horn, this does not help the switch retain its pressed state, and does not affect the set/accel/decel buttons not working.

I personally am skilled enough that I feel I could make any reasonable repairs, and we are going on a 900 mile trip in 2 weeks, (of which 700 miles is straight road thru nowhere) - so having it fixed by then would be a huge help.

any advice and or resources available? so far google results all seem to either say the switch (which would mean that the set button should still work) is broken, or that the PCB is damaged, which would make the cruise control light not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

As most people are aware pressing the brake pedal deactivates the cruise control.I don't know about Accords but some vehicles use a second switch on the brake pedal arm for the cruise cut off. If this is your case your brake lights would work but the cruise control would be disabled.

Comment: interesting to know! I actually determined that it was actually a combination of the switch and user error - the model of car requires the set button to be held down for 2-3 seconds to actually set the speed, after which it works normally, showing its just the cruise control switch. Part Number: 36770-SDA-A01 needs to be replaced.

Regardless, im marking yours as the correct answer, as its much better information for future users and more relevent to the actual question :)